# Google API key error

Tags: wordpress, api, google-maps

I have a problem with the google maps of wordpress template.
I created the API key and added it to the backend of settings theme but i see in the home page the map with error "For development purpose only".
How can I solve?
Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

A darkened map, or 'negative' Street View image, watermarked with "for development purposes only" is returned when any of the following are true:

- The request is missing an API key.
- The provided API key is invalid.
- Billing has not been enabled on your account.
- A self-imposed daily limit has been exceeded.
- The provided billing method is invalid (for    example an expired
  credit card).

Answer (score 0):

​In the browser console there is this warning message ---> 
util.js:227 Google Maps JavaScript API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
Nw.j @ util.js:227